# Java Registry Class?

Tags: java, php, registry

I'm fairly new to Java. I'm coming from PHP and I used to create registry classes in php using the magic __get and __set methods. So that other parts of the system can easily do:

```
registry.foo = new Foo();
```

I should mention I'm trying to create game engine. Here is my registry in Java atm:

```
class Registry {

    private static Map<String, Object> box = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public static Object get(String key) {

        if (Registry.box.get(key) != null) {
            return Registry.box.get(key);
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void set(String key, Object o) {
        Registry.box.put(key, o);
    }

}
```

Then for the other parts of the system to access the registry, I currently need this whole thing:

```
((Object) Registry.get("Object")).doSomething();
```

Which is really a lot of code. In php this would be accomplished by simply:

```
Registry.foo.doSomething();
```

Any way to make this a bit more simpler? I guess I could make public fields, but then the regsitry class would need to implicitly create these fields as the possibility of new objects may need to be added which are unknown to the registry class itself, which is.. annoying :P

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

This is a two pronged problem:

1. Java is a statically type language, and does not offer in-language flexibility for defining objects at runtime (you *can* use a library to synthesize classes at runtime, but, see #2)
2. A global registry for objects defeats a lot of safeties in a type-safe language. If your entire application centers around getting and putting objects into a global `Map`, there likely safer and less-coupled designs.

How can this be solved?

1. Redesign your application structure to not need a global map.
2. Use a dynamic language subset for Java (such as Groovy).
3. Use Scala 2.10 (JVM compatible) which features a `Dynamic` type which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Also, solutions 1 and 2/3 aren't mutually exclusive. A global service locator shouldn't be used to manage component dependencies regardless of language.

Answer (score 2):

First of all this method is too verbose:

```
public static Object get(String key) {
    if (Registry.box.get(key) != null) {
        return Registry.box.get(key);
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It could be just:

```
public static Object get(String key) {
   return Registry.box.get(key);
}
```

But second, this is definitely a bad design. Global repository - doesn't sound reasonable. A storage of objects of all types by string key - it's terrible.

Answer (score 1):

> Any way to make this a bit more simpler?

Not in any practical way. Java is a statically typed language, and the structure of objects has to be known up front. The very idea of an equivalent of PHP's `__get` and `__set` is antithetical to the language.

For what it's worth, your "registry" looks like bad design anyway. (Admittedly making some pretty wild assumptions from the little code you've shown.) You shouldn't need a global repository of what appear to be unrelated objects. You should consider some sort of dependency injection instead.

Based on your comment, instead of structuring your code like this:

```
class World implements GameSystem {

    public void update() {
        Registry.get("game").doSomething();
    }

}
```

you should do:

```
class World implements GameSystem {

    Game game;
    public World(Game game) { // and other dependencies
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void update() {
        this.game.doSomething();
    }

}
```

The idea is that components of your program don't really have any business knowing how to find the other components. It also makes dependencies between the components explicit, and helps you avoid circular dependencies.

Comment: Hmm. Dependency Injection?.. Well, would you have any suggestion as to what I should do though?

What I have is the main object "Game" which runs the gameloop etc.
It has a public field HashMap of GameSystems which in the gameloop, each GameSystems.update() method is run. One of the systems is the World system which when world.update() is run, it runs through a hashmap of "entities" which also has an .update() as well as a .render(). Thing is, some entities and some gamesystems need to ask the main game class certain things. Or some gamesystems need to communicate to other gamesystems.

Comment: @PetterThowsen I'll edit the answer to include an example with the classes you mentioned. That said, it's a notorious pattern, and you should find it discussed on the internet ad nauseam. Java also has a whole bunch of frameworks that implement it (Spring, Guice, Meld/CDI).